# Word 2011 for Mac: How to get to the top or bottom of a document?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

In Windows I used Ctrl+PageUp, currently on a Mac Air, doesn't have those buttons, how do I do  either one of this?

"Get to the top (page 1) of a document" or "Get to the bottom (last page) of a document"

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>left-arrow</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>right-arrow</kbd> for Home and End.